# Вывод последнего вопроса из списка опросов Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

На странице добавлен компонент "Текущий опрос", который выводит все вопросы из списка опросов. Подскажите, как вывести именно последний вопрос.

За вывод отвечает вот этот цикл:

```
<? foreach ($arResult["QUESTIONS"] as $k =>$arQuestion):
    $iCount++;?>
    <p><?= $arQuestion["QUESTION"] ?></p>
        <ul>
            <?
            $iCountAnswers = 0;
            foreach ($arQuestion["ANSWERS"] as $arAnswer):
                $iCountAnswers++;
                ?>
                <li>
                    <?
                    switch ($arAnswer["FIELD_TYPE"]):
                        case 0://radio
                            $value = (isset($_REQUEST['vote_radio_' . $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]]) &&
                                $_REQUEST['vote_radio_' . $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]] == $arAnswer["ID"]) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                            break;
                        case 1://checkbox
                            $value = (isset($_REQUEST['vote_checkbox_' . $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]]) &&
                                array_search($arAnswer["ID"], $_REQUEST['vote_checkbox_' . $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]]) !== false) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                            break;
                        case 2://select
                            $value = (isset($_REQUEST['vote_dropdown_' . $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]])) ? $_REQUEST['vote_dropdown_' . $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]] : false;
                            break;
                        case 3://multiselect
                            $value = (isset($_REQUEST['vote_multiselect_' . $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]])) ? $_REQUEST['vote_multiselect_' . $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]] : array();
                            break;
                        case 4://text field
                            $value = isset($_REQUEST['vote_field_' . $arAnswer["ID"]]) ? htmlspecialcharsbx($_REQUEST['vote_field_' . $arAnswer["ID"]]) : '';
                            break;
                        case 5://memo
                            $value = isset($_REQUEST['vote_memo_' . $arAnswer["ID"]]) ? htmlspecialcharsbx($_REQUEST['vote_memo_' . $arAnswer["ID"]]) : '';
                            break;
                    endswitch;
                    ?>
                    <?
                    switch ($arAnswer["FIELD_TYPE"]):
                        case 0://radio
                            ?>
                            <input type="radio" <?= $value ?> name="vote_radio_<?= $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"] ?>" <?
                            ?>id="vote_radio_<?= $arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"] ?>_<?= $arAnswer["ID"] ?>" <?
                                   ?>value="<?= $arAnswer["ID"] ?>" />
                                <?= $arAnswer["MESSAGE"] ?>
                            <?
                            break;
                    endswitch;
                    ?>
                </li>
            <?
            endforeach
            ?>
        </ul>
<?endforeach?>
```

Comment: А собственно вы сами разбирались как он выводит? пытвлись сделать по аналогии?

Comment: @Naumov Конечно разбирался. Для вывода именно последнего вопроса я поставил `<?= end($arQuestion["QUESTION"]);?>` Но как то не помогло, как исправить?

Comment: Наводку дам `var_dump($arQuestion["QESTION"]` сделай

Comment: @Naumov кеп выходит на охоту?наводку он даёт.......

Answer (score 1):

Вот готовый ответ, правда шаблон я модернизировал

```
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();

if (!empty($arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"])): 
?>
<div class="vote-note-box vote-note-error">
    <div class="vote-note-box-text"><?=ShowError($arResult["ERROR_MESSAGE"])?></div>
</div>
<?
endif;

if (!empty($arResult["OK_MESSAGE"])): 
?>
<div class="vote-note-box vote-note-note">
    <div class="vote-note-box-text"><?=ShowNote($arResult["OK_MESSAGE"])?></div>
</div>
<?
endif;

if (empty($arResult["VOTE"])):
    return false;
elseif (empty($arResult["QUESTIONS"])):
    return true;
endif;

?>
<div class="voting-form-box">
<form action="<?=POST_FORM_ACTION_URI?>" method="post" class="vote-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="vote" value="Y">
    <input type="hidden" name="PUBLIC_VOTE_ID" value="<?=$arResult["VOTE"]["ID"]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="VOTE_ID" value="<?=$arResult["VOTE"]["ID"]?>">
    <?=bitrix_sessid_post()?>
<?
//echo "<pre>";var_dump(end($arResult["QUESTIONS"]));echo "</pre>";?>
<ol class="vote-items-list vote-question-list">
<?
    $iCount = 0;
    $questions = array_values($arResult["QUESTIONS"]);
    $questions = $questions[count($questions)-1];
    //var_dump($questions);  
    //foreach ($questions as $key=>$arQuestion):
        $iCount++;
?>
    <li class="vote-item-vote <?=($iCount == 1 ? "vote-item-vote-first " : "")?><?
                ?><?=($iCount == count($questions) ? "vote-item-vote-last " : "")?><?
                ?><?=($iCount%2 == 1 ? "vote-item-vote-odd " : "vote-item-vote-even ")?><?
                ?>">

        <div class="vote-item-header">

<?
        if ($questions["IMAGE"] !== false):
?>
            <div class="vote-item-image"><img src="<?=$questions["IMAGE"]["SRC"]?>" width="30" height="30" /></div>
<?
        endif;
?>
    <div class="vote-item-title vote-item-question"><?=$questions["QUESTION"]?><?if($questions["REQUIRED"]=="Y"){echo "<span class='starrequired'>*</span>";}?></div>
            <div class="vote-clear-float"></div>
        </div>

        <ol class="vote-items-list vote-answers-list">
<?
        $iCountAnswers = 0;
        foreach ($questions["ANSWERS"] as $arAnswer):
            $iCountAnswers++;
?>
            <li class="vote-item-vote <?=($iCountAnswers == 1 ? "vote-item-vote-first " : "")?><?
                        ?><?=($iCountAnswers == count($questions["ANSWERS"]) ? "vote-item-vote-last " : "")?><?
                        ?><?=($iCountAnswers%2 == 1 ? "vote-item-vote-odd " : "vote-item-vote-even ")?>">
<?
            switch ($arAnswer["FIELD_TYPE"]):
                    case 0://radio
                        $value=(isset($_REQUEST['vote_radio_'.$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]]) && 
                            $_REQUEST['vote_radio_'.$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]] == $arAnswer["ID"]) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    break;
                    case 1://checkbox
                        $value=(isset($_REQUEST['vote_checkbox_'.$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]]) && 
                            array_search($arAnswer["ID"],$_REQUEST['vote_checkbox_'.$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]])!==false) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    break;
                    case 2://select
                        $value=(isset($_REQUEST['vote_dropdown_'.$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]])) ? $_REQUEST['vote_dropdown_'.$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]] : false;
                    break;
                    case 3://multiselect
                        $value=(isset($_REQUEST['vote_multiselect_'.$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]])) ? $_REQUEST['vote_multiselect_'.$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]] : array();
                    break;
                    case 4://text field
                        $value = isset($_REQUEST['vote_field_'.$arAnswer["ID"]]) ? htmlspecialcharsbx($_REQUEST['vote_field_'.$arAnswer["ID"]]) : '';
                    break;
                    case 5://memo
                        $value = isset($_REQUEST['vote_memo_'.$arAnswer["ID"]]) ?  htmlspecialcharsbx($_REQUEST['vote_memo_'.$arAnswer["ID"]]) : '';
                    break;
                endswitch;
?>
<?
            switch ($arAnswer["FIELD_TYPE"]):
                    case 0://radio
?>
                        <span class="vote-answer-item vote-answer-item-radio">
                        <input type="radio" <?=$value?> name="vote_radio_<?=$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]?>" <?
                                ?>id="vote_radio_<?=$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]?>_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" <?
                                ?>value="<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" <?=$arAnswer["~FIELD_PARAM"]?> />
                            <label for="vote_radio_<?=$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]?>_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>"><?=$arAnswer["MESSAGE"]?></label>
                        </span>
<?
                    break;
                    case 1://checkbox?>
                        <span class="vote-answer-item vote-answer-item-checkbox">
                            <input <?=$value?> type="checkbox" name="vote_checkbox_<?=$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]?>[]" value="<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" <?
                                ?> id="vote_checkbox_<?=$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]?>_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" <?=$arAnswer["~FIELD_PARAM"]?> />
                            <label for="vote_checkbox_<?=$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]?>_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>"><?=$arAnswer["MESSAGE"]?></label>
                        </span>
                    <?break?>

                    <?case 2://dropdown?>
                        <span class="vote-answer-item vote-answer-item-dropdown">
                            <select name="vote_dropdown_<?=$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]?>" <?=$arAnswer["~FIELD_PARAM"]?>>
                            <?foreach ($arAnswer["DROPDOWN"] as $arDropDown):?>
                                <option value="<?=$arDropDown["ID"]?>" <?=($arDropDown["ID"] === $value)?'selected="selected"':''?>><?=$arDropDown["MESSAGE"]?></option>
                            <?endforeach?>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                    <?break?>

                    <?case 3://multiselect?>
                        <span class="vote-answer-item vote-answer-item-multiselect">
                            <select name="vote_multiselect_<?=$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]?>[]" <?=$arAnswer["~FIELD_PARAM"]?> multiple="multiple">
                            <?foreach ($arAnswer["MULTISELECT"] as $arMultiSelect):?>
                                <option value="<?=$arMultiSelect["ID"]?>" <?=(array_search($arMultiSelect["ID"], $value)!==false)?'selected="selected"':''?>><?=$arMultiSelect["MESSAGE"]?></option>
                            <?endforeach?>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                    <?break?>

                    <?case 4://text field?>
                        <span class="vote-answer-item vote-answer-item-textfield">
                            <label for="vote_field_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>"><?=$arAnswer["MESSAGE"]?></label>
                            <input type="text" name="vote_field_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" id="vote_field_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" <?
                                ?>value="<?=$value?>" size="<?=$arAnswer["FIELD_WIDTH"]?>" <?=$arAnswer["~FIELD_PARAM"]?> /></span>
                    <?break?>

                    <?case 5://memo?>
                        <span class="vote-answer-item vote-answer-item-memo">
                            <label for="vote_memo_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>"><?=$arAnswer["MESSAGE"]?></label><br />
                            <textarea name="vote_memo_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" id="vote_memo_<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" <?
                                ?><?=$arAnswer["~FIELD_PARAM"]?> cols="<?=$arAnswer["FIELD_WIDTH"]?>" <?
                            ?>rows="<?=$arAnswer["FIELD_HEIGHT"]?>"><?=$value?></textarea>
                        </span>
                    <?break;
                endswitch;
?>
            </li>
<?
            endforeach
?>
        </ol>
    </li>
<?
        //endforeach
?>
</ol>

<? if (isset($arResult["CAPTCHA_CODE"])):  ?>
<div class="vote-item-header">
    <div class="vote-item-title vote-item-question"><?=GetMessage("F_CAPTCHA_TITLE")?></div>
    <div class="vote-clear-float"></div>
</div>
<div class="vote-form-captcha">
    <input type="hidden" name="captcha_code" value="<?=$arResult["CAPTCHA_CODE"]?>"/>
    <div class="vote-reply-field-captcha-image">
        <img src="/bitrix/tools/captcha.php?captcha_code=<?=$arResult["CAPTCHA_CODE"]?>" alt="<?=GetMessage("F_CAPTCHA_TITLE")?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="vote-reply-field-captcha-label">
        <label for="captcha_word"><?=GetMessage("F_CAPTCHA_PROMT")?><span class='starrequired'>*</span></label><br />
        <input type="text" size="20" name="captcha_word" />
    </div>
</div>
<? endif // CAPTCHA_CODE ?>

<div class="vote-form-box-buttons vote-vote-footer">
    <span class="vote-form-box-button vote-form-box-button-first"><input type="submit" name="vote" value="<?=GetMessage("VOTE_SUBMIT_BUTTON")?>" /></span>
<?/*?>  <span class="vote-form-box-button vote-form-box-button-last"><input type="reset" value="<?=GetMessage("VOTE_RESET")?>" /></span><?*/?>
    <span class="vote-form-box-button vote-form-box-button-last">
        <a name="show_result" <?
            ?>href="<?=$arResult["URL"]["RESULT"]?>"><?=GetMessage("VOTE_RESULTS")?></a>
    </span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```